# How would I implode a recordset column?

Tags: php, arrays, email, recordset, implode

I am trying to send an email to multiple email addresses which are contained in a database and sorted into a recordset...  The recordset has multiple columns, but I only need one: "Email".  I know that if I have them in an array I can implode them and separate them by commas, but I'm not sure how I could do that with a recordset column.  Anyone know how?

**Here is the recordset code:**

```
$colname_rsAllLeads = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_rsAllLeads = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
$query_rsAllLeads = sprintf("SELECT Email FROM Leads WHERE `User` = %s ORDER BY FullName ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsAllLeads, "text"));
$rsAllLeads = mysql_query($query_rsAllLeads, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);
$totalRows_rsAllLeads = mysql_num_rows($rsAllLeads);
```

**NEW CODE:**

```
$colname_rsAllLeads = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_rsAllLeads = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
$query_rsAllLeads = sprintf("SELECT Email FROM Leads WHERE `User` = %s ORDER BY FullName ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsAllLeads, "text"));
$rsAllLeads = mysql_query($query_rsAllLeads, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);
$totalRows_rsAllLeads = mysql_num_rows($rsAllLeads);

$row_rsAllLeads = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads) ) {
   $row_rsAllLeads[] = $row;
}

$glued = "";
$separator = "";
foreach( $row_rsAllLeads as $row ) {
   $glued .= $separator . $row['Email'];
   $separator = ", ";
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
} 

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {

    $startcode = $_POST['messagefield'];
    $replaced = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?="|\')/', '', $startcode );
    echo $replaced;
    $collectedleads = $row_rsAllLeads['Email'];
    echo $collectedleads;

    /*
 $to = $collectedleads;
 $subject = $_POST['subjectfield'];
 $body = $replaced;
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['FirstName'] . " " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['LastName'] . " <" . $row_rs_CurrentUser['Email'] . ">";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
  */

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO PendingEmails (`to`, subject, message) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($row_rsAllLeads['Email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['subjectfield'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['messagefield'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "Email Sent.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to glue it yourself. `implode()` is of no use here because you'd have to iterate thru your recordset, extract `Email`, put in separate array and then `implode()`. But since you are already iterating, you can glue it w/o temporary arrays and `implode()`, like this:

```
$glued = "";
$separator = "";
foreach( $row_rsAllLEads as $row ) {
   $glued .= $separator . $row['Email'];
   $separator = ", ";
}
```

**EDIT #1**

Your code needs a fix as well, because you fetching just **first** rowset, not all matching your where clause. It shall be like this (and you should change variable name from `row_...` to `rows_...` too):

```
$row_rsAllLeads = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads) ) {
   $row_rsAllLeads[] = $row;
}
```

so after all `$row_rsAllLeads` should be array of arrays.

Comment: Ok, and how would I use this?  Would I just put $row_rsAllLeads['Email'] in the `$to` part of the email function?  Would it already be formated then?

Comment: Depends on how you send your mail, but usually yes, that should suffice as "," is valid email separator. However I'd strongly suggest NOT using `TO:` but `BCC:` otherwise you will reveal all emails to every receipient. This is **very bad**.

Comment: I tried echoing out $row_rsAllLeads['Email'] and it just showed one email..  :/

Comment: Now its returning null...  Will you view my code above and tell me what im doing wrong please? :)

Comment: YOu have to remove `$row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);` because you "waste" 1rst matching row